# Array of Embedded Documents: comparison between fields and value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm approaching MongoDB and I have a database with this structure:

```
{ "_id" : 14185, "ranges" : [ { "first" : 17, "last" : 19 }, { "first" : 6, "last" : 9 } ] }
{ "_id" : 16478, "ranges" : [ { "first" : 26, "last" : 30 }, { "first" : 3, "last" : 5 } , { "first" : 3, "last" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : 17896, "ranges" : [ { "first" : 124, "last" : 130 }, { "first" : 140, "last" : 146 } ] }
```

So, I always have the `"ranges"` array, containing many documents: each one of these, has a `"first"` and `"last"` value.

Given a value, such as `29`, I'd like to write a query which gives me something like

```
{ "_id" : 16478, "ranges" : [ { "first" : 26, "last" : 30 } ] }
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a question $projection with $elemMatch like so:

```
db.collection.find({'ranges.first': {$lt: 29}  ,'ranges.last': {$gt: 29} },{ ranges: { $elemMatch: {first: {$lt: 29}  ,last: {$gt: 29} } }}).lean();
```